# How does DbContext.SaveChanges() work in C# when updating a table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following piece of code:

```
Customer customer = database.Customers.Where((X) => X.SSN = ssn ).FirstOrDefault();
customer.name = "John";
database.SaveChanges()
```

It simply updates the row that satisfies the Where. My question is: How can "SaveChanges()" know what to update?
It seems that it does not have access visibility to "customer" and it receives no parameters.

Comment: because `customer` is known to the EF database context object, and so it knows what row it relates to in the table, and that it should be taken into consideration when saving changes. You can read a lot more about it if you do some general reading on EF

Comment: ^ `because customer is known to the EF database context object` - which is because customer was returned from that context in the first place via a query. If you created a person instance yourself, SaveChanges would not see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework uses a `ChangeTracker` internally. This keeps the state of an entity as you add, update or delete it from the DbContext.

So, when calling `SaveChanges()` the change tracker knows what entities and what updates to send.

More info:

https://entityframework.net/change-tracker
or
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Answer (score 3):

Every time that you get a record from database EF tracks it and identifies by making an id for it. When SaveChanges call, it ask the ef to know which entity state has been changed and try to update database. But I recommend that set AsNoTracking when get an entity from database for performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because the database context knows what the primary key is.
Try to generate a database context for a table without a primary key and you will see that you get errors/warnings